# Simple raw_input and conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, raw-input

I created the simple code:

```
name = raw_input("Hi. What's your name? \nType name: ")
age = raw_input("How old are you " + name + "? \nType age: ")

if age >= 21
    print "Margaritas for everyone!!!"
else:
    print "NO alcohol for you, young one!!!"

raw_input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

It works great until I get to the 'if' statement... it tells me that I am using invalid syntax.

I am trying to learn how to use Python, and have messed around with the code quite a bit, but I can't figure out what I did wrong (probably something very basic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
name = raw_input("Hi. What's your name? \nType name: ")
age = raw_input("How old are you " + name + "? \nType age: ")
age = int(age)

if age >= 21:
    print "Margaritas for everyone!!!"
else:
    print "NO alcohol for you, young one!!!"

raw_input("\nPress enter to exit.")
```

You were missing the colon. Also, you should cast age from string to int.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `raw_input` returns a string not integer, so use `int()`. Otherwise the if-condition `if age >= 21` is always going to be False.:

```
>>> 21 > ''
False
>>> 21 > '1'
False
```

**Code:**

```
name = raw_input("Hi. What's your name? \nType name: ")
age = int(raw_input("How old are you " + name + "? \nType age: "))
```

The syntax error is there because you forgot a `:` on the `if` line.

```
if age >= 21
            ^
            |
       colon missing
```

Answer (score 2):

With python, indentation is very important. You have to use the correct indentation or it won't work. Also, you need a `:` after the if and else

try:

```
if age >= 21:
    print #string
else:
    print #other string
```